# Simple regex to replace first part of URL

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-4

Given

- `http://localhost:3000/something`
- `http://www.domainname.com/something`
- `https://domainname.com/something`

How do I select whatever is before the `/something` and replace it with `staticpages`?

The input URL is the result of a `request.referer`, but since you can't `render request.referer` (and I don't want a `redirect_to`), I'm trying to manually construct the appropriate template using `controller/action` where `action` is always the route, and I just need to replace the domain with the controller `staticpages`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regex like this:

```
(https?://)(.*?)(/.*)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/fV8nC7/1)**

[image]

As you can see in the Substitution section, you can use capturing group and concatenates the strings you want to generate the needed urls.

The idea of the regex is to capture the string before and after the domain and use `\1` + `staticpages` + `\3`.

If you want to change the protocol to ftp, you could play with capturing group index and use this replacement string:

```
ftp://\2\3
```

So, you would have:

```
ftp://localhost:3000/something
ftp://www.domainname.com/something
ftp://domainname.com/something
```

Comment: @james the regex I posted has 3 groups (1- the protocol, 2- the domain, 3- the rest). If you want to replace the protocol you could play with capturing group index, you could do: `statictext\2\3`. I posted the working demo link but you can check what I say here http://regex101.com/r/fV8nC7/2