# How to replace host part of a URL using javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex, url

How to replace the **host part** of a URL using javascript regex. This can be any kind of URL with or without http. Assume this text is from the content of a json file.

OldText:

```
{
   "auth" : {
     "login" : "http://local.example.com:85/auth/signin",
     "resetpass" : "http://local.example.com:85/auth/resetpass",
     "profile" : "http://local.example.com/auth/profile"
   }
}
```

Expecting a solution like:

```
var NewText = OldText.replace (/(some regex)/g, 'example.com');
```

To get NewText as:

```
{
  "auth" : {
     "login" : "http://example.com:85/auth/signin",
     "resetpass" : "http://example.com:85/auth/resetpass",
     "profile" : "http://example.com/auth/profile"
    }
}
```

I found the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26306968/simple-regex-to-replace-first-part-of-url), but that regex won't work in javascript.

Note: I'm looking for the Regex.

Comment: Do you specifically need to use regex? If you need to update the url from javascript you could potentially re-assign `window.location.host`.  [Reference](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-and-url-parts-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use the URL function and set a new hostname:

```
var oldUrl = "http://host1.dev.local:8000/one/two";
var url = new URL(oldUrl);
url.hostname = 'example.com';
url.href //'http://example.com:8080/one/two'
```

Comment: This is not supported in Edge, IE 11 and Safari

Comment: @E.Fortes
Yes, it is! Just tested on Edge right now:
var test = new URL("https://google.com/path?search=foo");
test.hostname = "localhost"; test.port= "7071"; alert(test.href);

Answer (score 1):

This could be achieved easily using:

```
var NewText = OldText.replace (/(https?:\/\/)(.*?)(:*)/g, '$1' + 'example.com' + '$3');
```

You are welcome to modify this with the best practice.

Comment: I think the correct regex pattern should be: `/(https?:\/\/)(.*?)(\/.*)/g`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is completely doable using regex.
Here's a small snippet for you, let me know if you want to add something else to it.

```js
var urls = [
    {
      url: "http://local.something.com:85/auth/signin"
    }, 

    {
      url: "local.anything.com/auth/profile"
    }
];
for(var i in urls) {
  var newUrl = urls[i].url.replace(/(http:|)(^|\/\/)(.*?\/)/g, 'https://example.com/');
  console.log(newUrl);
}
```

I am assuming, from

> without http

, you mean something like 'google.com'