# Replace string URL subdomain in pure JS or Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a URL as a string want to replace only the subdomian i.e. changing https://example1.com/home to https://example2.com/home. What is the most effective way to do this in Angular or pure JS?

Comment: Using `string.Replace()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace host part of a URL using javascript regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41582436/how-to-replace-host-part-of-a-url-using-javascript-regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest would likely be to split it twice, assuming you don't know what the sub domain will be, and then replace the sub domain using `replace()`.

With `split('//')[1]` you get all but the protocol, and `split('.')[0]` will give you the sub domain.

```js
var url = "https://example1.com/home"
var new_sub = "example2";

console.log( url.replace( url.split('//')[1].split('.')[0], new_sub ) )
```

---

With a regex you can do this

```js
var url = "https://example1.com/home"
var new_sub = "example2";

console.log( url.replace( url.split(/[\/\.]+/)[1], new_sub ) )
```